# Trying to update TestCase using TCMS API

Tags: testing, kiwi-tcms

I am having issues updating test cases. This is my python code:

```
for test_case in rpc_client.exec.TestCase.filter({'pk': x}):
    rpc_client.exec.TestCase.update(x, test_case)
```

I am getting this error:

```
 <Fault -32603: 'Internal error: Product ID is required for category'>
```

Can someone explain to me what is the issue? For testing purposes I just get the text case and then I call the update function. I am not sure what Product ID I have to include. Official documentation does not have any information about what this attribute actually stands for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing this? It doesn't make sense! You are filtering a particular test case (so it will be only 1) and then try to update the same object with the same values?

Comment: My god. I have written it down (i.e. For testing purposes I just get the text case and then I call the update function). And I have found the solution. Thanks for your help anyway.